# Function to round off value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Any function in sql which rounds off value.

i.e if the value is 15.66 i should get 16 and 15.44 then i should get 14.

is there any function which does this work

Comment: Why 14 for 15.44 it should be 15 ?  You can use `round()` provided by sql server http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLRoundingFunctions.aspx

Comment: no typo ? "15.44 then i should get 14"

Comment: So what for 12.44 or 11.32?

Comment: Rounds off or does 5/4 rounding? Do you really mean 15.44 -> 14?

Comment: whats the business rule behind 15.44 -> 14, rounding off will not solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mmmh... should be

```
round(your_value, 0)
```

which rounds your value to the second argument number of digits.
I.e:

```
round (15.27,1) = 15,3
round (15.27,-1)= 20
```

(yes, it works with negative significances as well ;)

oh, I just considered the 15.44->14 to be a typo

Answer (score 1):

Use the below syntax

```
Select **ROUND(column name, decimals)** FROM <table name>
```

Set decimals to 0 to achieve your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )`

[Go through this link](http://goo.gl/YNWZD)

Although its very easy and you could have easily found out